# Crystal Reports: Distinct Header Rows

Tags: crystal-reports

I have datasource which joins a parent and a detail table, so the parent data is duplicated for each detail record like this:

```
ParentCol   DetailCol-1   DetailCol-2
    A           Orange          15
    A           Pinaple         10
    A           Grape            8
    B           Orange          10
    B           Grape            7
```

I need to use a Main report to show the parent column on the main report and a subreport to link it with the same data to the subreport using the "ParentCol" column. I'll pass the same datasource to both the main report and the subreport, because I won't make two queries and we want to improve performance with this idea. Notice that I cannot use grouping to achieve this.

---

Page 1 - Main report

```
 ParentCol:  "A"
```

---

Subreport

```
                  Orange        15
                  Pinaple       10
                  Grape          8
```

---

---

Page 2 - Main report

```
 ParentCol:  "B"
```

---

Subreport

```
                  Orange        10
                  Grape          7
```

---

How can I achieve this?

### Edit:

@Ryan is right, the thing is that I was trying to use the same dataSource on different information contexts. I can certainly visualize the desired data using only a master/detail schema and the master columns won't repeat but the detail will be shown as desired.

If i use a subreport with the same data used on the main report, I would potencially generate a cartesian product shown on the detail, even if I use a Subreport Link. It won't work.

So, I'll avoid using the same query for a main report and a Subreport

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using subreports? You'll need to avoid them if you want to limit the report to a single query.

Comment: I don't see the need for subreports either. You can accomplish this with a single grouping level (ParentCol), a group header section, and a detail section. If you need to preserve the original sort order, make sure the group is configured for "original order."

Comment: I'm using subreports because this is not the only data I'll be showing on the report.
So, Should I stop using subreports in order to accomplish this task? why?

Comment: The reasons not to use a subreport here: (1) so far nothing indicates that you need one, (2) a subreport adds design complexity, and (3) subreports often slow down report execution.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Crystal Report which you have taken already.

Choose Insert option and select the SubReport to insert SubReport.

Then Right click on the Sub Report and select the Edit SubReport and do binding to the subreport with the fields you want.

Then come to Main Report.

Again Right Click on the SubReport and choose the Change the SubReportLinks tab to make a relation between the Main Report Field and SubReport Field.

Now click on preview. You will get the desired Output.

Comment: I found out that using the same dataset on a main report and a subreport is not a good idea because I will never have the desired output

Comment: This approach would work and does avoid a cartesian product, but as discussed above, a subreport doesn't appear to be necessary in this case.